# How to dynamically populate anchor tag in MVC View using ViewData value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to populate an anchor tag's `href` value in the View using a ViewBag value? What I want to be able to do is something like this:

View:

```
<a href="<%= ViewBag.MyURL %>" title="My URL">"<%= ViewBag.MyURL %>"</a>
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.MyURL = "http://www.Google.com";
        return View();
    }
```

How do I go about doing this correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here was the way this worked to dynamically update a href anchor tag using MVC and Razor:

Controller (this could also be set in a code block within the View if needed as well):

```
ViewBag.MyURL = "http://www.Google.com";
```

View:

```
<a href="@Html.Raw(Html.AttributeEncode(ViewBag.MyURL))" title="@Html.Raw(Html.AttributeEncode(ViewBag.MyURL))"> @Html.Raw(Html.AttributeEncode(ViewBag.MyURL))</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the following in the controller:

```
ViewBag.myURL = "http://www.my-url.com";
```

Then in the view you have:

```
@Html.Raw("<a href=\"" + ViewBag.MyURL + "\" title=\"" + ViewBag.MyURL + "\">" + ViewBag.MyURL + "</a>")
```

Html.Action helper is typically used when posting to another controller and/or action within the same web site.
Html.Raw is good for building links to external websites.

Comment: This did not work. I get a runtime warning stating **File '<%=ViewBag.myURL%>' was not found**, and then the URL shows up as "_"

Comment: @atconway Can you please post the updated, relevant code from both the controller and the view

Comment: @atconway The updated code you posted in the OP works perfectly for me.  The error message shows you have a lower case my in myURL, but the code you posted has upper case My in MyURL, so maybe that was part of the issue?

Comment: Nah I was just obfuscating it from the real names I was using and mistyped only here on SO. I actually pasted your code and I get the *same* message. Did you run yours?

Comment: @atconway Yes I have run it several times to make sure.  Are you using Razor view engine or aspx view engine?  If I run this code exactly as typed with the aspx script tags in a Razor view and click on the generated link then I can get an error similar to yours.

Comment: I am using the Razor view engine. Is there a better way to do this with a HTML helper? Can the `ActionLink` work

Comment: I gave you a upvote because it got me thinking in the right direction using Html.Raw, but it was still not working perfectly for me. See my answer for the solution that worked for me.